# Django with Postgres - Sub query slow

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

Django Postgres - Sub query slow

Hello,

I want to select players with their current location (not in the futur and closest from now) ordered by Player.registered_at. I also want to filter the Player regarding their current location with DRF.

Here are my models :

```py
class Player(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(
                fields=["closed", "deleted"],
                condition=Q(closed=False, deleted=False),
                name="opened_player_index",
            )
        ]
    registered_at = models.DateTimeField(_("registerd at"), db_index=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    closed = models.BooleanField(_("closed"), default=False)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(_("deleted"), default=False)
    
    
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class PlayerLocation(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(
                fields=["player", "active_since", "location"],
                name="player-active-since-location",
            )
        ]

    active_since = models.DateTimeField(_("active since"), db_index=True)

    player = models.ForeignKey(
        Player, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="locations"
    )
    location = models.ForeignKey(
        Location, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="+"
    )
```

Here is my query :

```py
class PlayerQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def with_location(self):
        # Get current healthcare facility as SubQuery
        current_player_location = PlayerLocation.objects.filter(
            player_id=OuterRef("pk"), active_since__lte=Now()
        ).order_by("-active_since")

        return self.annotate(
            # add current location of player queryset
            lookup_location=Subquery(
                current_player_location.values("location")[:1]
            ),
            location_name=Subquery(
                current_player_location.values("location__name")[:1]
            ),
        )
```

Here is the output of the explain analyze postgres query (for the count) :

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS "__count"
FROM
  "player"
WHERE
  (
    NOT "player"."closed"
    AND NOT "player"."deleted"
    AND (
      SELECT
        U0."location_id"
      FROM
        "player_location" U0
      WHERE
        (
          U0."active_since" <= (STATEMENT_TIMESTAMP())
          AND U0."player_id" = ("player"."id")
        )
      ORDER BY
        U0."active_since" DESC
      LIMIT
        1
    ) = 1
  );
```

```
 Aggregate  (cost=115889.72..115889.73 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=35.327..35.330 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on core_episode  (cost=119.41..115889.56 rows=64 width=0) (actual time=9.575..34.905 rows=3219 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: ((NOT closed) AND (NOT deleted))
         Filter: ((SubPlan 1) = 1)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 9800
         Heap Blocks: exact=136
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on opened_player_index  (cost=0.00..119.39 rows=12800 width=0) (actual time=0.469..0.470 rows=13019 loops=1)
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=13019)
                 ->  Index Only Scan using player-active-since-location on player_location u0  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=13019)
                       Index Cond: ((player_id = player.id) AND (active_since <= statement_timestamp()))
                       Heap Fetches: 1
 Planning Time: 4.303 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 14
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 0.854 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.516 ms, Emission 8.393 ms, Total 9.762 ms
 Execution Time: 71.447 ms
(18 rows)
```

The indexes are used by the query planner, but I find the query somehow slow. There are 700k players but only 10k active (not closed and not deleted). Is there a better
way of doing this query ?

Thanks for your inputs and advices.

Kind Regards.

Joel

I tried to transform the subquery by a joint. I tried to use a Max instead of an order by with a limit 1.

Comment: Please post a readable plan with proper formatting.  I tried to fix the formatting, but is more screwed up than I can fix.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know what would *actually* make your query faster, because we do not have your data. In your case, though, I would use a raw SQL query, which allows you to write your own query exactly how you want, bypassing the Django ORM. See the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/sql/).

Depending on your exact table and column names, you may try something like this :

```py
current_player_location = Player.objects.raw(
    """
    select distinct on (player) a.*, b.active_since, c.name
    from player a
    join (
        select *
        from player_location
        where active_since < now()
        order by active_since DESC) b on a.id = b.player
    join location c on b.location = c.id
    where not closed and not deleted

    """
)
```